# Find duplicate in list of extracted entities

Tags: java, java-8

```
private boolean hasDuplicates(Recipe recipe) {
    List<Recipe> currentRecipes = new ArrayList<>();

    Stream.of(this.breakfast, this.lunch, this.dinner).forEach(meal -> {
        currentRecipes.add(meal.getRecipe());
        currentRecipes.add(meal.getSnack());
    });
    currentRecipes.add(this.snack);

    return currentRecipes.contains(recipe);
    };

}
```

// Imagine getter and setter for all fields.

```
public class Menuplan {
  private Meal breakfast;
  private Meal lunch;
  private Meal dinner;
  private Recipe snack;
}

public class Meal {
  private Recipe recipe;
  private Reicpe snack;
}
```

I got the above method to test, if a Menuplan has already the given recipe (as snack or recipe) assigned.

I wonder if there is a more elegant/shorter way to write the function.

Comment: `return Stream.concat(Stream.of(this.breakfast, this.lunch, this.dinner).flatMap(meal -> Stream.of(meal.getRecipe(), meal.getSnack())), Stream.of(this.snack)) .anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual(recipe));`

Comment: instead of using arraylist use `hashSet` and override its equals & hashcode method, it will save time for this calculation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution doing all in one Stream, is

```
private boolean hasDuplicates(Recipe recipe) {
    return Stream.concat(
        Stream.of(this.breakfast, this.lunch, this.dinner)
            .flatMap(meal -> Stream.of(meal.getRecipe(), meal.getSnack())),
        Stream.of(this.snack))
   .anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual(recipe));
}
```

The three stream elements `this.breakfast, this.lunch, this.dinner` get the same treatment of invoking `meal.getRecipe()` and `meal.getSnack()` to form a new stream, which gets concatenated with the single element stream just holding `this.snack`.

`anyMatch` will return `true` as soon as it finds an element fulfilling the condition. Otherwise, it will return `false`.

You may consider moving the one element that doesn’t fit the pattern common to the others out of the Stream operation instead:

```
private boolean hasDuplicates(Recipe recipe) {
    return this.snack.equals(recipe) ||
        Stream.of(this.breakfast, this.lunch, this.dinner)
            .flatMap(meal -> Stream.of(meal.getRecipe(), meal.getSnack())
            .anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual(recipe));
}
```

Another alternative is

```
private boolean hasDuplicates(Recipe recipe) {
    return this.snack.equals(recipe) ||
        Stream.of(this.breakfast, this.lunch, this.dinner)
            .anyMatch(meal -> meal.getRecipe().equals(recipe)
                           || meal.getSnack().equals(recipe));
}
```

Comment: Really neat. This is definitely the best answer and should be accepted!

Answer (score 1):

You probably should avoid streams

```
private boolean hasDuplicates(Recipe recipe) {
    for (Meal each : Arrays.asList(breakfast, lunch, dinner)) {
        if (each.getRecipe().equals(recipe) || each.getSnack().equals(recipe) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return snack.equals(recipe);
}
```

Comment: Why should I avoid streams?

Comment: You asked for a shorter, more elegant way. Streams don't help you in this case.

Comment: I actually agree, this reads nice and concise. The downside is that it will be hard to enhance, especially when more OR conditions need to be added in the future. When you compare your code with the approach from Holger in his comment, you will see that he can easily add new "things" such as extra snacks or so ... just by adding new elements into streams.